# 'io.github.resilience4j.common.retry.configuration.RetryConfigurationProperties$InstanceProperties' has no property 'register-health-indicator'

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am using spring boot 2.5.8.
In my application.properties:

```
                resilience4j.retry.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator= true
```

I get the following error:
'io.github.resilience4j.common.retry.configuration.RetryConfigurationProperties$InstanceProperties' has no property 'register-health-indicator'

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-timelimiter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to see health, events etc. of any resilience4j patterns below config will be sufficient;

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details = always
```